# Accretion disk formation

Tags: gravity, binary-star, celestial-mechanics, accretion

Why a mass transfer in a binary star system, from the less dense star to the denser star forms an accretion disk? Why the material does not fall directly to the denserstar?

Comment: Welcome to Astronomy SE! Although the question is a valid and interesting one, I would appreciate a bit more information, in particular on the background of your question (why you are asking) and what you know so far. In dubito pro reo, I just assume that it is not an exam question. For more guidance see [ask].

Comment: Because it is hard to get rid of angular momentum in space.. (i.e. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LHvR1fRTW8g "Why hitting the sun is hard")

Comment: an accretion disk can form if the mass transfer is dynamically stable